# Where can I edit the "Service Unavailable" page/template?

Tags: templating

Sorry if this is an obvious thing - can't seem to find an answer in the docs.
Where can I edit the system offline message? "service unavailable"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try creating a `503.html` file at the root of your templates folder. This should override the default template located at `craft/app/templates/503.html`.

Comment: Cool, this did the trick. Noticed the comments in the craft/app/templates/404.html as well. Thanks!